# Cannot read property 'match' of undefined (ace-angular)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, ace-editor

I installed ace-angular with npm and created ace editor inside angular, it looks like this:

```
[HTML]
<div id="editor" ace-editor="aceOptions" ng-model="aceContent"></div>

[JS]
$scope.aceOptions = {
    method: "javascript",
    theme: "monokai",
    onLoad: function(editor, session, ace){
        // Do on load
    }
}
```

And it keeps saying "TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined" every time I load page with ace editor.
Screenshot: [image]

EDIT:

```
[AngularJS]
var app = angular.module("cloude", ["ngRoute", "ace.angular"]);
```

It seems that error will not appear if I remove "ace.angular" so I guess it is problem with module?

Comment: Ive never encountered this, so for me a live example (codepen.io / jsfiddle) would help

Comment: @EricG http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/12557/ Here is code, but I can't make it work, I can't load NodeJs Module into JSFiddle

Comment: It's not working. May be you can raise issue in its github repository https://github.com/jayralencar/ace-angular

Comment: sounds like you are setting value of ace  to undefined

Comment: @auser, that was my case. Muchas gracias!